# SSJS Rows.Update multiple fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Can you update more than 1 field with SSJS Rows.Update?

SFMC Documentation
Update(object, filtercolumns, filtervalues)

```
This function updates the specified row with the specified information.
Arguments:

* object - Contains the name of the column to be updated and the value to which to update it
* filtercolumns - Identifies the columns in which to search for data
* filtervalues - Identifies the values to be used in the search
```

object references column...singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
de.Rows.Update({UpdateOneName:'UpdateOneValue',UpdateTwoName:'UpdateTwoValue'},['FilterName'],['FilterValue']);
```

I was actually missing the quotes around the FilterName.